# How To Format NSPredicate when doing an "IN" search with Coredata and NSFetchRequest

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I have a very simple fetch request that i want to execute. One of my entities has an attribute called smartCollectionIds and it is of type transformable. I use this attribute to store an `NSArray` of simple strings. In my code i use an `NSfetchedResultsController` to populate a tableview. The predicate im using is as follows:

```
predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"smartCollectionIds!=nil && (%@ IN smartCollectionIds)",@"87F173A5-863D-4ECE-9673-A61D8F1E01FC-6285-000009A9CBAF3290"];
```

however this causes a crash, specifically at the pint when i perform a fetch. However, if i first use a fetch to load all my objects into an array, and then filter them out with the above predicate, the app does not crash, and i get my results as expected. So basically 
**THIS CODE BELOW DOES NOT WORK**

```
-(void) tryTO
{
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Tweetary" inManagedObjectContext: [[ChubbyEyetwitterEngine sharedInstance] getManagedObjectContextForUse]];

NSPredicate *predicate;

predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"smartCollectionIds!=nil && (%@ IN smartCollectionIds)",@"87F173A5-863D-4ECE-9673-A61D8F1E01FC-6285-000009A9CBAF3290"];

NSSortDescriptor *secondarySortKey = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"created_at" ascending:FALSE] autorelease];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease] ;
[request setEntity:entity];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
[request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                             secondarySortKey
                             ,nil]];
[request setFetchLimit:30];  //30


NSError *error;

NSArray *results = [[[ChubbyEyetwitterEngine sharedInstance] getManagedObjectContextForUse] executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

if (error != nil)
{
     NSLog(@"Results are %d",[results count]);

}else{
    NSLog(@"findAllObjectsInContext error %@",error);

}
```

}

**BUT THIS WORKS**

```
  NSArray *tweets = [Tweetary findAllObjectsInContext:[[ChubbyEyetwitterEngine sharedInstance] getManagedObjectContextForUse]];

NSLog(@"Before filter count is %d",[tweets count]);

predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"smartCollectionIds!=nil && (%@ IN smartCollectionIds)",@"87F173A5-863D-4ECE-9673-A61D8F1E01FC-6285-000009A9CBAF3290"];

predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"smartCollectionIds!=nil && (%@ IN smartCollectionIds)",@"87F173A5-863D-4ECE-9673-A61D8F1E01FC-6285-000009A9CBAF3290"];

NSArray *bNames = [tweets filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

NSLog(@"FINAL Results %d",[bNames count]);



+ (NSArray *)findAllObjectsInContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context;
  {


 @synchronized(self){

NSEntityDescription *entity = [self entityDescriptionInContext:context];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setEntity:entity];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if (error != nil)
{
    //handle errors
    //NSLog(@"findAllObjectsInContext error %@",error);
}
return results;
  }
 }
```

In a nutshell, i need my fetch predicate to work when using NSfetchedResultsController instead of first loading up my objects into an array, and then applying my filter predicate. Can anyone point me in the right direction/ figure out why the predicate works only after i load my unfiltered data set into an array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Core Data fetch request with a predicate is translated to a SQLite query and executed
on the SQLite level. A transformable array is stored as some blob in the SQLite database,
therefore treating it as array in a fetch request does not work.

If you fetch the elements first, the blob is transformed back to an array
when the property is accessed. Therefore filtering the array of fetched objects works as expected.

I don't think there is any workaround. You cannot filter on transformable properties
in a fetch request.